# To have RAM-based filesystem in OSX?

Tags: memory, filesystem

I would like do real-time monitoring, discussing one part of it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213230/16920) about counting quickly. 
No packages about it in homebrew.

How can you have RAM-based filesystem in OSX?

Comment: Reading between the lines, I assume you'd like a RAM-backed filesystem (the equivalent of a "RAM disk")?

Comment: @mjturner Yes. I want a RAM-backed filesystem. Any idea how in OSX?

Answer (score 5):

Mac OS includes support for RAM-based filesystems via `ramfs`. Everything is RAM backed so it's incredibly fast with near zero latency, but the contents are lost upon reboot.

To create one and mount it under `/tmp/mymount`, create a script with the following contents and run it:

```
#!/bin/sh
NUMSECTORS=128000       # a sector is 512 bytes
mydev=`hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$NUMSECTORS`
newfs_hfs $mydev
mkdir /tmp/mymount
mount -t hfs $mydev /tmp/mymount
```

The above was adapted from the `hdiutil` manual page

You can also do it in a one-liner (adapted from [here](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-create-a-4gbs-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/)):

```
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RAM Disk' $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://XXXXX)
```

Where `XXXXX` is the size in 2048 byte blocks. There is also a useful script in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/456803/create-ram-disk-mount-to-specific-folder-in-osx) on Superuser.